# Siri unable to determine my location despite location services enabled

Tags: macos, high-sierra, siri, geolocation

**Specs:** MacBook Pro Late 2012 running macOS High Sierra

I am trying to ask Siri to tell me what the weather is in my current area, but apparently Siri is saying that it doesn't know where I am, despite having location services enabled.

I tried disabling and re-enabling Location Services for Siri through System Preferences, but that didn't seem to fix anything, and Siri said the same thing: "could not determine your location."

Then, I disabled Location Services itself, but when I re-enable it, Siri still can’t tell me where the Mac is.

My timezone is also correct, but Maps isn't able to determine my current location either.

What are next steps in fixing this?

EDIT - Already fixed this by installing the latest macOS update.

Comment: Location should provided by the router which services the wi-fi or wired network connections you are using, and it is usually supplied by the ISP. The device you're using to connect to the internet is not providing this information. Do you have the Time Zone specified correctly in System Preferences > Date & Time?

Comment: When you open Maps and try to map your location, how far from where you are does it resolve? Same with your time zone in system preferences. It would be good to know if Siri alone is “lost” or Siri is getting bad data from the main location services at the OS level. Be sure to edit these clarifying details into your question body.

Comment: You haven' recently slipped over an event horizon?

Answer (score 2):

Signing into iCloud and turning on both Bluetooth and Wi-Fi ensures that your Mac has the best chance of finding its location.   I believe that if you sign into iOS devices that happen to have GPS or location services working, your Mac might be smart enough to figure out where it is based on sharing the same Internet connection in proximity, but I am not sure.

The primary way that location is determined as if Apple knows the IP address you are reaching so be sure you turn off all VPNs and get on as open a network is you can initially. The second way is trilateralization from known WiFi access points that your WiFi can see. You don’t have to join those networks, but you need a viable network connection back to Apple.

Comment: Also - if you have any network filters, try to disable them. In my case I have Cisco Anyconnect VPN installed, and its filters prevent Siri from getting my location - even though the app is not running.